# Loading a HTML file using JS

Tags: javascript, json

I was following this tutorial on loading files with Javascript. I've followed the tutorial and no file loads. Here's the my code:

```
<script type="application/javascript"
        src="http://server2.example.com/Users/1234">
</script>
```

Now in this tutorial ([Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)) It says It should load the file into a div. Do you guys know what's happening?

Comment: So, the response is expected to be the inner-html in JSONP format right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Loading JSON**

The "tutorial" you mentioned, is the Wiki page on JSON. The line of code you provided is copied exactly from that page, and if you read the contents correctly, it isn't talking about loading **HTML** files from javascript, but loading **JSON data** from Javascript.

In fact, the page clearly says that this approach cannot allow you to access the JSON data, because it isn't assigned to do anything, and even if it does load the data as an object, you have no pointer to that object!

Instead, the same page suggests using something like

```
<script type="application/javascript"
      src="http://server2.example.com/Users/1234?jsonp=parseResponse">
</script>
```

so that you can use the function `parseResponse` with the data.

**Loading HTML**

Since you want to load some additional HTML, after you load the page, you should do something like:

Example Code: *(partly copied from the page I gave you)*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadXMLDoc(filename) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        after_load_function(xmlhttp.responseText);
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function after_load_function(responseText) {
      document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = responseText;
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      loadXMLDoc("your_html_filename.html");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So, you're trying to explain that It's not possible to load a HTML file into a Div using JS?

Comment: You can do that, but not by writing the `<script>` tag. Instead, you should search for AJAX XMLHttpRequest. Useful reading: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp

Comment: Okay - yes. But Instead of using a button how would you make it load straight away when user has loaded the site?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to load an HTML file from an HTML file, right? There are many ways to do that in server-side, rather than waiting for the first HTML to load, and then loading another one. Although, if for some reason this needs to be done in JS, you can use the `window.onload` function to load your HTML without any user action.

Comment: Yes, I want to load a HTML file onto a div. In this link you gave me, witch code would I change to get the text or file loaded into the div straight away on the site load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37985/discussion-between-shaun-and-mavrosxristoforos)

Answer (score 0):

you may use jquery `ajax` or `get` function which will fetch data from given url and print that data into given div

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$.get( "http://server2.example.com/Users/1234?jsonp=parseResponse"
       ,function( data ) {
                        $( "body" ).append( "Name: " + data.name ) // John
                        .append( "Time: " + data.time ); //  2pm
                        }
       ,"json" );
</script>
```

Refer this link for more details [Jquery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)